Cannot build app on real device due to Undefined symbols
I am encountering a linker error in Xcode while trying to build my project, which uses Alamofire 5.8.1 and Firebase 11.5.0. The error is as follows:
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _main, referenced from:
      <initial-undefines>
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I've Tried:
Ensured that all dependencies are installed and up to date via Swift Package Manager (SPM).
Verified that the Target Membership includes the necessary files.
Checked Build Phases to confirm that all source files are properly listed under Compile Sources.
Cleaned the build folder (Shift + Command + K) and deleted the DerivedData folder.

I accidentally deleted @main from
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

